# Is there a way to say "thanks to" in French but in a sarcastic manner?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

I know there is «grâce à», but that is only used for positive things. There's also «à cause de», but that doesn't give me the same effect I want. For example, how would I say this in French:

> Thanks to the coronavirus, no one can leave their homes.

Merci d'avance !

Comment: @vc74 *À cause* isn't sarcastic.

Comment: Isn't sarcasm implied by the tone and the context rather than by the wording? I would say it's the same in French as in English, while other languages may have different words for expressing sarcasm I don't know. For example "Thanks to the coronavirus there are much less driving accidents" is I think much less sarcastic than "Thanks to the coronavirus there are now many available spots in retirement homes" (which is borderline dark humor)

Comment: When I want to imply sarcasm when writing, I use quotes. On the internet I would use smileys to avoid falling in the a scenario described in [Poe's Law(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law). In speech, in case tone wouldn't be enough I make frequent use of air quotes. When I'm not sure the target audience will get sarcasm, I try to refrain using it.

Answer (score 11):

Like with the English "thanks to", the tone is essential to make clear what you mean with *merci*.

I would then suggest:

> Plus personne ne peut sortir de chez soi, merci le coronavirus !

As per @Xi'an's comment:

> Plus personne ne peut sortir de chez soi, merci qui ? Merci le coronavirus !

Here is an example of use found in the *[Femme actuelle](https://www.femmeactuelle.fr/sante/sante-pratique/innovations-medicales-merci-le-coronavirus-2102717)* magazine:

[image]

---

[Another one](https://jack.canalplus.com/articles/lire/ca-sent-le-crame-pour-le-festival-coachella-merci-le-coronavirus?tl=fr?tl=fr) (jack.canalplus.com) where *merci* is clearly sarcastic:

[image]

---

Same tone [here](https://actu.fr/normandie/caen_14118/maxime-beaussire-apres-son-immense-deception-je-pense-que-la-boxe-c-est-fini-pour-moi_36711031.html) (actu.fr):

[image]

Comment: Chacun a plus ou moins de second degré. Cela dit, l'exemple cité n'est sans doute pas le meilleur car on s'attend effectivement à un article indiquant que malgré ses côtés hautement négatifs, le coronavirus apporte quand-même quelques avantages.

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, c'est vrai, le premier exemple est plus ironique que sarcastique. Je viens d'en ajouter deux plus convaincants.

Comment: On pourrait aussi ajouter un "merci qui ?" avant "Merci le coronavirus" pour renforcer le sarcasme.

Comment: [Suppression de commentaires] J'ai supprimé tous les commentaires qui relevaient d'un débat qui n'a pas sa place ici, et je supprimerai tous les futurs commentaires qui y feront référence.

Answer (score 4):

The most common way is to use the plain translation of "thanks to" and in saying it to use an intonation that will communicate the sarcastic effect, although that is not absolutely necessary, but with a neutral intonation and depending on the subject not much sarcasm might come through.

- Grâce au coronavirus personne ne peut quitter son habitation.

Comment: On pourrait connaitre la raison de ces votes négatifs ?

Comment: Je ne comprend pas non plus les downvotes... tout comme dans "Thanks to the Coronavirus, ...", le sarcasme est implicite. Tout comme dans la réponse de jlliagre.

Comment: @LaurentS. En fait, je ne vois pas de sarcasme dans cette rhétorique mais de l'ironie. « Le sarcasme (du grec ancien σαρκασμός / sarkasmos) désigne une moquerie ironique, une raillerie tournant en dérision une personne ou une situation ».  Il n'y a pas de situation tournée en dérision. ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasme))

Comment: L'exemple est mal choisi je pense. Il est assez difficile avec cette seule phrase de savoir si cela est dit d'une manière positive ou négative... De plus je dois bien avouer que j'ai parfois un peu de mal moi-même a catégoriser une phrase comme sarcastique ou ironique. Je ne pense pas que l'OP voulait aller si loin dans la nuance...

Comment: @LaurentS. Il y a peu de chance que l'idée de la réclusion, même dans des  lieux d'habitation qui sont les nôtres, soit quelque chose que nous puissions trouver plaisant ; d'après ce que je comprends à partir des nouvelles les français haïssent le confinement.

Comment: @LPH Je gagne au moins dix heures par semaine depuis la mi-mars grâce au télétravail généralisé. Moins de pollution, moins d'avions au dessus de chez moi. Merci le coronavirus !

Comment: @jlliagre Dans ce sens, c'est acceptable; l'ironie est certaine, mais la phrase de l'OP n'indique rien de positif.

Comment: Concernant la nuance entre l'ironie et le sarcasme, on peut aussi étayer avec ce qu'en dit H. Suhamy (Que sais-je? 1889): «L'ironie à l'état pur consiste à dire d'un escroc: *“Admirez ce génie de la finance!”* tandis que le sarcasme se contentera de *“Cet homme tranquille et respecté que voyez là-bas avait promis de nous tirer d'affaire.”*

Comment: Selon ceci, est-ce que l'ironie pourrait dire: *«Tout le monde entre ses quatre murs! Quelle époque stimulante!»* et le sarcasme: *«Bravo Corona! Tout le monde chez soi et finis les embouteillages!»*?

Comment: ...et les votes négatifs... Ironie ou sarcasme? Je m'y perds aussi un peu sur le pourquoi...

Comment: @Pasunclue 1/ Oui, c'est ironique, puisque comme le dit la définition dans la Wikipédia, on «  dire le contraire de ce que l'on pense en faisant comprendre que l'on pense le contraire de ce que l'on dit ». 2/ Dans ce second cas, je ne vois pas un cas de situation tournée en dérisoire: on ignore l'essentiel d'une situation, qui est son aspect tragique, et on la vante pour un certain côté profitable qu'on lui découvre. Il me semble qu'alors, encore une fois comme le dit la Wikipédia, qu'il s'agit plutôt «  d'une bravade contre les valeurs, les convenances et les principes de la société » (1/2)

Comment: @Pasunclue et donc il faudrait parler de cynisme au lieu de sarcasme. 3/ Les votes négatifs sont quelque chose à quoi il faut se résigner ; ceux qui les distribuent n'ont aucun désir de discuter ou d'améliorer quoi que ce soit et semblent agir selon des  motivations autres que celles que l'on puisse  avancer comme répondant au but de ce  site, excepté celle de signaler une information douteuse mais elle ne semble pas sincère. (2/2)

Comment: Je vois le sarcasme dans le vote négatif. Toutefois, j'apprécie ton réponse (spécifiquement l'intonation) et je crois qu'il mérite d'être contrebalancer (+1).

Comment: C'est la réponse parfaite.

Comment: @WillCrawford  Will Crawford, I thought I knew that name!

Answer (score 3):

> On ne peut même plus sortir de la maison, [vive](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vive#Interjection) la [*COVID-19* (ou *maladie à coronavirus 2019*)](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26557671) !

L'interjection *vive*<sup>1</sup> pour l'« exclamation en l’honneur de quelqu’un, ou d’une chose dont on se félicite de la présence » (Wiktionnaire), employée sarcastiquement<sup>2</sup> avec la désignation officielle (de l'OMS) de la maladie dont il s'agit.

---

<sub><sup>1.</sup> « When used as a general exclamation of honor, as in “**Vive** la France!” it is usually translated by “long live” in English. Cognate to Spanish (and Italian and Portuguese) [*viva*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viva#Spanish), of identical usage. Note that in modern French "vivent" is no longer used for the third person plural imperative; e.g. Vive les vacances (Yay for vacations) », [*Usage notes*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vive#Usage_notes), « vive » version anglaise (Witkionary). [*Long live*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long%20live)...</sub>
<sub><sup>2.</sup> L'[antiphrase](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3225), consistant à employer un mot ou une phrase dans un sens contraire à son sens véritable, est la principale figure de style utilisée pour faire de l’ironie (BDL, incluant la formulation). « Beaucoup de phrases exclamatives ne se distinguent des énonciatives que par des éléments phoniques et, dans l'écrit, par le point d'exclamation [...]. L'antiphrase a besoin aussi du ton exclamatif pour donner au lecteur l'impression qu'on souhaite : *Elle est propre, votre auge !*  [= elle est sale]
(J. RENARD , *Poil de Car.*, Pl., p. 728.) » (LBU14, §401 a). Ça tombe bien, on a une [*locution interjective*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3337) qui est suivie par un point d'exclamation. «  À l'inverse de l'ironie, qui consiste à dire le contraire de ce que l'on pense en faisant comprendre que l'on pense le contraire de ce que l'on dit, le sarcasme est plus difficile à déceler. En effet, être sarcastique c'est dire le contraire de ce que l'on pense, sans montrer qu'on pense le contraire de ce que l'on dit. » (Wikipédia, [*sarcasme*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasme)). On commence à entrer dans le vif du sujet...</sub>

Comment: Le nom exact du coronavirus est SARS-CoV-2, pas covid 19 qui le nom de la maladie, laquelle a subi une transformation de genre en cours d'année avec la bénédiction de l'Académie, montrant que cette institution n'est pas si réfractaire au changement qu'on le dit...

Comment: Merci, c'est vrai ! @jlliagre

Comment: Ce pourrait n'être pas sarcastique. _On ne sorte plus de la maison pour visiter les grand-parents, vive la COVID-19!_ Est-il sarcastique ou est le parleur (e.g. le petit fils) vraiement joyeux de ne les visiter plus?

Comment: @Ángel «On ne peut **même plus** sortir de la maison» → c'est bel et bien sarcastique, à moins que vivre enfermé et manger des araignées soit le but ultime de l'existence du parleur.

Comment: @Ángel Bon réflexe de demander. Intéressant. Voir le commentaire de Pas un clue. Mais ça serait aussi sans doute formulé différemment : « Plus besoin de rendre visite aux grands-parents, vive la COVID-19 ! ».

Comment: C'est peut-être même possible avec l'adverbe [_vivement_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vivement) ? Ça pourrait faire l'objet d'une question.